# Rickshaw.Graph.RangeSlider.Preview not updating when data getting changed

Tags: javascript, rickshaw

when rickshaw graph data changes, the slider preview not getting change/update. I am unable to use the slider preview.

getting the following exception

```
Rickshaw.Graph.HoverDetail.Rickshaw.Class.create._calcLayoutError rickshaw.js:2282
Rickshaw.Graph.HoverDetail.Rickshaw.Class.create.render rickshaw.js:2257
Rickshaw.Graph.HoverDetail.Rickshaw.Class.create.update rickshaw.js:2173
(anonymous function) rickshaw.js:2308
```